# Conexão Externa Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, segurança, aplicação-desktop

Tenho uma aplicação java em meu computador funcionando offline junto com uma conexão no banco, com acesso total. Gostaria de saber como que eu faria para que, se for instalado este programa em um outro computador, a pessoa trocar a senha do root e tentar sincronizar com o banco q está na nuvem para ter acesso, como eu cortaria esta conexão, não permitindo o acesso externo.

Comment: Por meio de arquivo externo de properties, configurada na máquina do cliente. Sugiro que este arquivo seja criptografado para não deixar a senha completamente visível em plain text.

Comment: Configure o pg_hba.conf para que seja permitida a conexão como superusuário apenas para as máquinas dos administradores.